# Using a python ssh session which asks for a password to the private key

Tags: python, ssh

I am using an ssh connection to remote server via username and password which works fine. I intended to automate some file transactions from my machine to this remote server and attempted to write a python script which would use ssh connections.

```
from paramiko import SSHClient
from scp import SCPClient

ssh = SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ip = ... # id of the remote server
username = ... # my username
password = ... # my password
ssh.connect(ip, username=username, password=password) # <- this line causes a dialog box to appear

scp = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport())
scp.get(local_path=local_target, remote_path=os.path.join(remote_target, local_target))
```

The actual dialog box asks for:

> Enter password to unlock the private key

I do not remember my private key to be honest so I cannot provide it to the dialog box. My question are

a) why python asks for private key whereas in cli there is no need for it? Is cli using ssh-agent implicitly to perform the initial handshake while python does not?
b) Is there a way to imitate the cli behavior and get rid of the necessity for password in python to unlock my private key?
c) Is there a way to retrieve my private key from my username-password I am aware of? I found some relevant answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/887605/546065) but I couldn't apply it in my case.
In *Passwords and Keys* program there isn't any entry in login for "Unlock Password for user@host". Instead I found an entry under *OpenSSH keys* where under properties I get a dialog box which has some options:

1. Export, 2) Change Passphrase and 3) Delete SSH key.

Would changing *Passphrase* be a solution for example? [This relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311141/enter-password-to-unlock-the-private-key-connecting-to-digitalocean-droplet-lo) states so. I am only concerned if this change would affect my working cli ssh connection with the server though.

Comment: Acording to the [documentation](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect), the're a keyword argument `look_for_keys` with default value `True`, which will look for keys in the default path `~/.ssh`. I suspect you have a id_rsa or some other keys there which cause this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried setting `look_for_keys` to False but the dialog still appears